# Tannaka categories and reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schemes, group-schemes, tannakian-category

The group associated to a Tannaka category $T$ over a field is pro-reductive if and only if $T$ is semi-simple.

Pro-reductive groups make sense over any scheme.

Is there an extension of the theory of Tannakian categories over fields to "Tannakian categories over a scheme" such that "semi-simple Tannakian categories" correspond to "pro-reductive group schemes"?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether the representations of pro-reductive groups over schemes are semisimple --- this is not even true over fields of nonzero characteristic.